# pass ref to a class component with React.cloneElement and render prop

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, ref, clone-element

I'm writing a component that handle some internal `state` according to a `ref` of it's child (a mouse event related to that child's ref for example).
This component is using a `render-prop` to pass on the relevant piece of `state` to it's child, and render the child with the `ref` attached via `React.cloneElement` util.

The problem is that when the child is a `class` component, for some reason the `ref` is not available, and i can't find a way to render it as it's a react element object with a type of `function` (after i clone it of course).

But if the child is just a `DOM` node like  a `div` for example, it is working as expected.

My work-around is to check the type of the child, and if it is a type of `function` I'll wrap the cloned element with my own `div`, if it's just a dom node then render as is.
However, i would like to not wrap the child with an extra `div` as i don't want to add unnecessary `DOM` nodes.

Here is a basic code example, most code removed for brevity:
**The Parent component:**

```
class Parent extends Component {

    attachRef = node => {
        this.ref = node;
    }

    render() {
        const { render } = this.props;
        const { someValue } = this.state;
        const Child = render(someValue);
        const WithRef = React.cloneElement(Child, {
            ref: this.attachRef
        });
        if (typeof WithRef.type === 'string') { // node element
            return WithRef;
        }
        else if (typeof WithRef.type === 'function') {
            // this is a react element object.. not sure how to render it
            // return ?
        } else {
            // need to find a way to render without a wrapping div
            return (
                <div ref={this.attachRef}>{Child}</div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**The usage:**

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Parent render={someValue => <div> {someValue}</div>} />
                <Parent render={someValue => <Menu someValue={someValue} />} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When i render regular DOM nodes like the first example it works fine, when i try to render the `Menu` (which is a `class` component) it doesn't work as mentioned above.

Comment: Is Menu a SFC (functional component), would you mind sharing your Menu component?

Comment: i have no problems with SFC's as they will return a `DOM` node. `Menu` can be anything actually, i can't really know as my component will be some sort of a library. in the example `Menu` is a `class` component and as i mentioned this is where things are getting off.

Comment: The caveat is that ref can't be used to point to functional component since it doesn't have instance.

Comment: and from the snippets above, it's hard to tell how is ref actually used besides creating the `this.ref` reference, could you be more specific about what you mean `ref is not available`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had almost an identical issue.
i chose to use [findDOMNode](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) from `react-dom`, you can see the full solution [in react-external-click](https://github.com/sag1v/react-external-click/blob/master/src/components/ExternalClick.js).

Although the warning notes:

> findDOMNode is an escape hatch used to access the underlying DOM node.
>   In most cases, use of this escape hatch is discouraged because it
>   pierces the component abstraction.
>
> findDOMNode only works on mounted components (that is, components that
>   have been placed in the DOM). If you try to call this on a component
>   that has not been mounted yet (like calling findDOMNode() in render()
>   on a component that has yet to be created) an exception will be
>   thrown.
>
> findDOMNode cannot be used on functional components.

I think this is the better solution for this particular challenge.
It let's you be "transparent" to the consumer, while being able to target the component in the `DOM`.

Ok here it is, grabbing the ref:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.ref = findDOMNode(this);
    // some logic ...
}
```

this is how i use a render function with no wrapper of my own:

```
render() {
        const { children, render } = this.props;
        const { clickedOutside } = this.state;
        const renderingFunc = render || children;

        if (typeof renderingFunc === 'function') {
            return renderingFunc(clickedOutside);
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }
}
```