# Reference to DOM instance undefined when passing to render prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, jsx

I'm trying to use some nested render props to compose a button that optionally takes an icon, which in turn optionally takes a tooltip that will show when the icon is hovered or clicked. To do this I think I will need to pass a reference to the `Icon` down to the child `Tooltip` component.

Based on what I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51083981/1252748) I'm doing

```
  // Icon

  componentDidMount() {
    this.iconInstance = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    console.log('Icon mounted, instance', this.iconInstance);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Icon render iconInstance', this.iconInstance);
    return (
      <span style={{ display: 'inline' }}>
        <span>{this.props.iconText}</span>
        {this.props.tooltip({ iconInstance: this.iconInstance })}
      </span>
    );
  }
```

And then within `Tooltip`, a listener would be added

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Tooltip mounted', this.props);
    // fails because iconInstance is undefined
    // this.props.iconInstance.addEventListener(
    //   this.props.mouseEvent,
    //   this.showTooltip
    // );
  }
```

Immediately after I set `this.iconInstance`, it can be logged so that seems to be working. However in the render function I'm getting undefined.

There might be a way to use `forwardRef` to do this, however I could not find a way to pass the `Tooltip` component as a render prop from the `App` component down through `Icon` and add a `ref` prop to it eg, `{this.props.tooltip(this.iconInstance)}` gets an error saying you can't pass refs like that and it will fail.

[Full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/4z5lr99190)

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score -2):

ComponentDidMount is a method which gets executed after the render method is called for the first time.
It is ComponentWillMount method which is called before the render method is executed.

Comment: It is in context with what you were discussing with the above person.

Comment: Ah, then this should be a comment in the above discussion, not its own answer, but anyway, this is not really in question. Thanks though.

Comment: We need 50 as the minimum reputation score to comment on any post and by reading my answer you downvoted and decreased my score by 1.